# Can you set default values for request.get() (not post.get)?

Tags: django, post, get, request, default-value

I have 2 HTML submission fields under one submit button, one of which is optional. I'm using the 'get' method to retrieve submitted data, but I want the optional field to have a default value just in case the user submits an empty form. If I don't do this, I get a MultiValueDictKeyError.

```
if request.method == 'GET': 
        # required
        name = request.GET['name']
        # optional
        color = request.GET['color']
```

I think a possible solution is try / except for every field, but is there a more elegant method? I know for get.post() you can do something like

```
color = request.POST.get('color', False)
```

But this doesn't seem to work for just request.get()

Any ideas?

Thanks,

fertileneutrino

Comment: It definitely works for request.GET as well. .get() is a method on all dictionary-like objects.

Comment: But I can't add default values to request.get(). I still get the same error if I try to.

Comment: You're trying to add items into request.GET? I don't think it allows assignment. You'd need to copy it to a new dictionary and do that, but this seems really convoluted. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Confused here... `request.get()` won't work, but `request.GET.get()` should. Did you just mistype or were you actually using `request.get()`?

Comment: I was actually using request.get(). request.GET.get('color', False) gives an "'instancemethod' object is not subscriptable" error. Looks like I have more debugging to do

Comment: Are you *sure* you had `request.GET.get('color', False)` with parentheses `()`? Not subscriptable suggests you were using braces `[]`.

Comment: Got it to work. Good answer! I ended up replacing all [] with (), and came back here to see your suggestion